# Probability of duration of a phone calls like a draw made random with replacement

Tags: probability

The durations of phone calls taken by the receptionist at an office are like draws made at random with replacement from a list that has an average of $8.5$ minutes (that's $8$ minutes and $30$ seconds) and an SD of $3$ minutes. Approximately what is the chance that the total duration of the next $100$ calls is more than $15$ hours?

First convert everything into seconds. The mean is $8.5$ minutes. $8.5$ minutes is $510$ seconds for one call,

so it's $100$ times that amount for $100$ calls. $510\times 100=51000$ seconds

The SD is $3$ minutes. $3\times 60=180$ seconds for one call,

the variance is the SD squared. $\sigma=180^2=32,400$ seconds.

Multiply the variance by $100$, then take the square root of it for the SD for $100$ calls.

$SD=\sqrt{32400\times 100}=1,800$ seconds.

$x$ is the time for $100$ calls. The mean is the mean for $100$ calls, SD is the SD for $100$ calls. You'll use the $z$ score to find the probability:

$15$  hours$\times60$  minutes$\times 60$  seconds$=54,000$ seconds

$$z=\frac{x−\bar{x}}{SD}= \frac{54,000-51,000}{1,800}=1.67$$

Area under normal curve Lower end $-5$

and upper end $1.67=95.22\%= 0.9522$ THEREFORE $P(t\gt54,000)=1-0.9522=0.0482$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 100 random variables, each with average $\mu_0=8.5$ minutes and standard deviation $\sigma_0=3$ minutes. The central limit theorem thus tells you that the sum of these random variables is approximately normally distributed with $\mu=100\mu_0=850$ minutes and standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{100}\sigma_0 = 30$ minutes.

You're looking for the probability that such a standard distribution yields a value greater than 15 hours, or equivalently greater than $15\cdot 60 = 900$ minutes. If a random variable $X$ is normally distributed with average $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then the probability that $X \leq a$ (or equivalently $X < a$, since the normal distribution is continuous) is $$
  \mathbb{P}(X \leq a) = \Phi\left(\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma}\right) \text{,}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the *standard* normal distribution, i.e. the one with average 0 and standard deviation $1$. You're interested in the probability that $X = X_1+\ldots+X_{100}$ is *greater* than 900 minutes, and must thuse compute $$
  \mathbb{P}(X > 900) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq 900) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{900 - 850}{30}\right) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \text{.}
$$

Now you just need to use a table (or software) to evaluate $\Phi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \approx 0.952$ and get $$
   \mathbb{P}(X > 900) \approx 0.048 \text{.}
$$

So you simply forgot to invert the probability you got at the end, i.e. your value (which is $\Phi\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$) is the probability that the calls take *less* than 15 hours in total.

Btw, there's an easy way to see that your answer *cannot* be correct. You're asking from the probability that the value is *greater* than some value which itself is *greater* than the mean of the distribution. Since the normal distribution is symmetric, the mean is also the median, and thus the probability *cannot* be larger than 0.5, i.e. 50%. And since the distance from the mean isn't particularly small compared to the standard deviation (your distance is 50, the standard deviation is 30), it'll have to be *substantially* smaller than 50%.

Comment: @statistics-student13 Please don't shout... i.e., kindly have your caps-lock key fixed.